# Design 32 bit arithmetic logic unit (ALU)

Tags: verilog, alu

I write this coder for an ALU. This ALU controlled with `ctrl` signals and do some works like add, subtract, and, or, ... When output is zero, `oZero` signals should be active.

I have some errors in marked lines. What is my mistake?

```
module ALU_32 (iA, iB ,iCin ,ctrl, oCarry,oZero, out);    
input [31:0] iA,iB;
output [31:0] out;
input iCin,ctrl;
output oCarry,oZero;
reg [31:0] out;
reg oCarry;
reg oZero;
always@ (ctrl)
    begin 
        case(ctrl)
            4'b0: out<=iA&iB;
            4'b0001: out<=iA|iB;
            4'b0010: {oCarry ,out}<=iA+iB;
            4'b0011: out<=iA~|iB;    //error
            4'b0100: 
            begin 
                if(iA==iB)
                    out<=32'b1;
            end  
            4'b0101: out<=iA-iB;  //error
            4'b0110:    //error
            begin 
                if(iA<iB)
                    out<=32'b1;
                else
                    out<=32'b0;
                end
            4'b0111:   out<=iA*iB;     //error
            4'b1000: out<=iA/iB;        //error

        end
       always@(out)
           begin
               if(out==0)
                   oZero<=1;
               end

      endmodule
```

Comment: @toolic :In compiling. and these are massage: `Syntax error. Unexpected token: 4'b0110[_BINARY_BASE]. Expected tokens: '#' , ''' , '(' , '{' , 'assign' ...  ` and `Syntax error. Unexpected token: ~|[O_RNOR]. Expected tokens: '[' , '(*' , '(' , '++' , '--' ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Qiu pointed out, `iA~|iB` should be `~(iA|iB)` and you are missing an `endcase`. In addition to that:

1. `ctrl` needs to be 4-bits wide. IE `input [3:0] ctrl`
2. Combinational block need to declare all elements in the sensitivity list or use auto-sensitivity. With `always @(ctrl)` the simulator will not use see changes in `iA` or `iB`. Instead use `always @*` for auto-sensitivity. you should always use auto-sensitivity for combinational logic unless you are limited to the 1995 version of the IEEE Std 1364 (odds are you are not), in which case you need `always @(ctrl or iA or iB or iCin)`. Auto-sensitivity (`@*` or `@(*)`) was added to the standard in 2001.
3. You should not use non-blocking assignments (`<=`) with combinaitional logic, use blocking assignments (`=`). Non-blocking should be used to assign flip-flops and latches.
4. `out` and `oCarry` are not assigned a known value in every condition, this infers them as latches. Latch logic designs are prone to timing issues and need to be used with caution. Most FPGAs have a limited number of latches and some have some. A coding style change can remove the infered latch and there are two main ways to do so.

   1. Assign the outputs in every condition. Make sure a default condition is declared in an case-statement:

      ```
      always @* begin
        case(ctrl)
        4'b0000 :
          begin
            out = iA&iB;
            oCarry = 1'b0;
          end
        // conditions assigning both 'out' and 'oCarry'
        default:
          begin
            out = 32'0;
            oCarry = 1'b0;
          end
        endcase
      end
      ```
   2. Assign the values to a default value before the case-statement. The case-statement will override the default values.

      ```
      always @* begin
        // default value
        out = 32'd0;
        oCarry = 1'b0;
        // calculate value, override default
        case(ctrl)
          4'b0000 : out = iA&iB;
          // ...
          4'b0010: {oCarry ,out} = iA+iB;
          // ...
          4'b1000: out = iA/iB;
        endcase
      end
      ```
5. `oZero` is also an inferred latch. It can only be assigned to 1, there is no path to 0. You can:

   - `always @* oZero = (out==0);`
   - Merge the always block with `oZero = (out==0);` below `endcase`
   - `assign oZero = (out==0); // Make sure 'oZero' is a wire (not reg)`

---

Other suggestions *(optional)*

1. ANSI style header. Added in IEEE Std 1364-2001 and supported by all modern simulators and synthesizers. It is more compact than the Non-ANSI style of IEEE Std 1364-1995.

   ```
   module ALU_32 (    
     input [31:0] iA, iB,
     input        iCin,
     input [3:0]  ctrl,
     output reg  oCarry, oZero,
     output reg [31:0] out );
   ```
2. You suggested there where errors with `iA*iB` and `iA/iB`. In verilog, there is nothing wrong. Synthesis tools may have an issue because 32-bit by 32-bit multiplier / dividers tend to take a lot of resources. You may need to pipeline the operations in separate modules. FPGA may have a predefined module, so check the data sheet.

Answer (score 1):

`~|` operator that you used in `4'b0011: out<=iA~|iB;` is treated by your IDE as a reduction operator and not as a NOR operation. To fix that you can use e.g. following construct:

```
out <= ~(iA | iB);
```

Second problem is that you forgot to use `endcase` keyword at the end of your `case` construct.

Check [edaplayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Ah4) to see those changes applied to your code.